# get clock_sec from nibobee-library <clock.h>

Tags: c, clock

I am trying to access the variable `clock_sec` from the [library](http://doku.nibo-roboter.de/nibobeelib/clock_8h.html) `nibobee/clock.h`. But it seems the variable is always zero.

Does someone have a hint?

```
uint32_t time = clock_sec;
```

Unfortunately I did not find the documentation in English.

Comment: Have you contacted the author at the address left in the middle of the **library** link you provided?

Comment: You mean because it's in German? No I did not.

Comment: My only thought was he may have an English version he can point you to, and I would suspect he can communicate in English. I'd shoot him an e-mail and ask. (and obviously, do not re-post his address on SO or any other public forum -- he would probably not thank you for that)

Comment: @greenhoom I've looked at the code. In `nibobee/clock.h` the declaration for `clock_sec` is `extern volatile uint32_t clock_sec;`. The definition of  `clock_sec` is in `clock.c` as `volatile uint32_t clock_sec;`, so unless you are **both** including `clock.h` (or defining  `extern volatile uint32_t clock_sec;` in your code) **and** compiling your code with `clock.c` or including the library in your compile string, `clock_sec` will **always** be `0` because it isn't declared or set.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Unfortunately he does not have an English version. Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try asap.